# How to enable post types on Page Attributes?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-attributes

How can I have post types shown on Page Attributes? For instance I have a custom post type which is `product`, and I want **show** it on Page Attributes **alongside** with the existing WP post types: `page`, `post`.

So I want so have a **dropdown options** and the user can **switch around** these post types:

```
post
page
product
```

My code in `functions.php`:

```
function product_init() {
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Products'),
            'singular_name' => __('Product'),
            'all_items' => 'All Products'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Products'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            // 'excerpt',
            // 'trackbacks',
            //'custom-fields',
            //'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            )
        );
    register_post_type( 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_init' );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: so you need a drop down like `Page Attributes` -> `Template` for custom post type?

Comment: @DHL17 see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer - `post-type-switcher` plugin below:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

Though it would be great without a plugin.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a plugin for that.